# I have three Button but I want that just one of them rotate

Tags: ios, swiftui

It's two day that I'm struggling through this problem. I'm learning Swiftui with #100DaysOfSwift by HackingWithSwift. By the end of the day I was asking to take a previous project and editing it.

The app simply put three Button in a VStack and ask user to guess the right flag.

```
VStack{

                ForEach(0..<3){ number in
                        Button(action:{
                            self.flagTapped(number)
                        }){
                            FlagImage(numberOfTheFlag: self.countries[number])
                        }.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.rotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                }
                // more code...
```

The function flagTapped() is:

```
func flagTapped (_ number: Int) {
     debugPrint(rotation)

    if number == correctAnswer {
        scoreTitle = "Correct! Great job."
        score += 1
        withAnimation{
            self.rotation += 360
        }
    } else {
        withAnimation {
            // wrong animation
        }
        wrongFlag = number
        scoreTitle = "Wrong! That's the flag of \(countries[number])"
    }
    showingScore = true
}
```

The problem is: all the buttons rotate at same time.

[THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRsgR.gif)

How can I fix?

thank you all in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you to [Mamaessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12233264/mamaessen), I resolved my problem. Need definitely to improve my @Binding/@State skill, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that your `rotation` value is applied to all the buttons. Therefore all buttons will be updated once your `rotation` changes.

What you want to do it to apply a different `rotation` value to each one of your buttons and then change just that one `rotation` for the button that needs to spin. This here might bring you on the right track.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<3){ number in
                RotatingButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RotatingButton: View {

    @State private var rotation: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.flagTapped()
        }){
            Circle()
        }.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(Double(self.rotation)), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    }

    func flagTapped() {
        withAnimation {
            self.rotation += 360
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but... Now I've other 1563 issues trying to let my two struct talk each other. 


But thank you, again.